# php array loop to get array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have a $date array like this:

```
[1]=> array(11) {
    ["meetingname"]=> string(33) "win2008connectcurrent0423131"
    [0]=> array(3) {
        ["scoid"]=> string(7) "3557012"
        ["datecreated"]=> string(19) "2013-05-23 10:02:39"
        ["numparticipants"]=> string(1) "3"
    }
    [1]=> array(3) {
        ["scoid"]=> string(7) "3557012"
        ["datecreated"]=> string(19) "2013-05-23 14:40:06"
        ["numparticipants"]=> string(1) "3"
    }
}   

foreach($date[0] as $key =>  $meetings){
    print "$key = $meetings\n";////yields scoid = 3557012
}
```

And, as you can see above, I am looping over individual elements. The first element (not indexed) is always `meetingname`; the rest of the elements are indexed and themselves contain arrays with three elements in each array--in the above code they are `[0]` and `[1]`.

What I need to do is make the `$meetings` as an array containing `[0]` and then `[1]` etc, depending on the number of elements. So essentially, the output for print should be an array (I can also use `var_dump`) with key/values of `[0]` but right not it only outputs individual keys and their values, for example, as you can see above, `scoid=3557012`. I will need, something all keys/values in the $meetings variable, something like:

```
{
    ["scoid"]=> string(7) "3557012"
    ["datecreated"]=> string(19) "2013-05-23 10:02:39"
    ["numparticipants"]=> string(1) "3"
}
```

How can I fix the foreach loop for that?

Comment: Why don't you include the arrays you want inside your question? `print_r` is okey, but still everybody will be wasting time converting it into a real array.

Comment: I think I have the desired array as code block at the nearly very end of my Question--that's how the $meetings **should** look like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please Try this. hope it help.

```
foreach($date as $key =>  $meetings){
       if($key == "meetingname")
         continue;
       else
         print "$meetings\n";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a new array and add the meetings to that one

```
<?php
$meetings = array();
foreach($date[1] as $key=>$meeting) {
  if (!is_int($key))
    continue;  //only handle numeric keys, incase you ever change the name of the first key 'meetingname'

  $meetings[] = $meeting
}

var_dump($meetings);
?>
```

Comment: Hi, $date[1] is not an element--it must be $date[0]. Anyway, @Hasina's answer is working. Thanks for your help!